# how and whre to find latest version of of firebase-ui?

Tags: java, firebase, firebaseui

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'
```

What is the Latest version of firebase-ui for appcompat-v7:27.1.1?

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'
```

Firebase-ui this version is not working also for appcompat-v7:27.1.1.

Answer (score 3):

The latest version of Firebase-UI is always shown here:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/

The version of Firebase-UI is intended to match the version of the Firebase libraries, not the compatibility libraries.  You can almost certainly ask for a greater version of the compat libs than are required by Firebase-UI.